# How to reuse connect function database java mysqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm writing an application with java form and sqlite and I have a function to connect to database and get data like this:

```
public ResultSet getResultSet(String query) {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        // create a database conn
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\nguye_000\\Desktop\\qlct.db");

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        return rs;
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
      // if the error message is "out of memory", 
      // it probably means no database file is found
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if(conn != null)
          conn.close();
      }
      catch(SQLException e) {
        // conn close failed.
        System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Why when I call it in main function I get an error?

```
Database db = new Database();
ResultSet rs = db.getResultSet("SELECT * FROM qlct_options");
while(rs.next()) {
    // read the result set
    System.out.println("id = " + rs.getInt("option_id"));
    System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("option_key"));
    System.out.println("value = " + rs.getString("option_value"));
}
id = 0
name = null
value = null
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_MISUSE]  Library used incorrectly (out of memory)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.next(JDBC3ResultSet.java:83)
    at qlct.Qlct.main(Qlct.java:18)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I want to everytime run a any query I can use getResultSet() function and pass query into it. I can't write a code like this http://chuoidichvu.com/downloads/Database.java, each time I need to write a query I do try{} catch{}, final{}. It's hard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return a `ResultSet` from your function *after* having close the connection (in the `finally` part of the outer `try`).

This causes an error, since you can scan the `ResultSet` *only* while the `Statement` and the `Connection` are still open.

To obtain your objective (“reuse connect function database java mysqlite”) you have to “rearrange” the abstraction that you are trying to define. For instance you could pass to your method a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (if you are using Java 8) that processes the result *inside* it.

Comment: Another option is to simply leave the connection open for the duration of the application.